# how to display data from a database to display on full calendar?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried to display data from the database to be displayed in Full Calendar, but the data would not appear in fullcalendar, I have tried to see references in several web tutorials that integrate this, but it still hasn't worked

my reference :

1. https://www.patchesoft.com/fullcalendar-with-php-and-codeigniter
2. https://www.brianrevie.com/how-to-add-full-calendar-codeigniter
3. [How To show fetch events from database with time in fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873910/how-to-show-fetch-events-from-database-with-time-in-fullcalendar)

I have the following data

```
[{"title": "Work", "start": "2019-08-01", "end": "2019-08-01" },{"title": "Work", "start": "2019-08-02","end": "2019-08-02"}]
```

this my js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
    height: 440,
    editable: true,
    eventSources: [
      {
        color: '#306EFE',   
        textColor: '#ffffff',
        events: "<?= base_url('UserDashboard/getAbsen'); ?>"
        // events: [{
        //   title: 'My Big Event',
        //   start: '2019-12-09',
        //   end: '2019-12-10'
        // },
        // {
        //   title: 'My Second Big Event',
        //   start: '2019-12-11',
        //   end: '2019-12-13'
        // },
        // {
        //   title: 'My Second Big Event',
        //   start: '2019-11-11',
        //   end: '2019-11-13'
        // },]
      }
    ]
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

this my controller

```
public function getAbsen() {
    $month = date('11');
    $year = date('Y');
    $id_karyawan = 26;
    // $data = $this->m_data->rekapAbsen($id_karyawan, $month, $year);
    $data = $this->m_data->rekapAbsenFullCalendar($id_karyawan);
    foreach ($data as $val) {
        $id = $val["id_attendance"];
        $tgl_db = $val["date_log"];
        $tgl = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tgl_db));
        $d = $val["days"];
        $c = $val["check_in"];
        $o = $val["check_out"];
        if ($d == 'Saturday') {
            $days = 'Day Off';
        } if ($d == 'Sunday') {
            $days = 'Day Off';
        } else {
            if ($c == '00:00:00') {
                $days = 'Day Off';
            } else {
                $days = 'Work';
            }
        }

        $data_array[] = array(
            // 'id_attendance' => $id,
            'title' => $days,
            'start' => $tgl,
            'end' => $tgl,
            // 'allday' => '0'
        );
    }
    // var_dump($data);
    echo json_encode($data_array);
}
```

and this my fullcalendar, data not showing

[image]

where is the fault?

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs show](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) there are a few methods of specifying a JSON feed of events.

The simplest option is just:

```
events: '/myfeed.php'
```

Alternatively, you can use the extended form if you want to also specify some options:

```
eventSources: [
{
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    color: 'yellow',
    textColor: 'black'
}
```

Your code does not use either of these formats - you have `eventSources` but without a `url`, and with `events`.

Update your code as follows:

```
eventSources: [{
    color: '#306EFE',   
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    url: "<?= base_url('UserDashboard/getAbsen'); ?>"
}]
```

The rest of your code works fine, [here's a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/2hjy8Lvt/).